# How should a custom configuration entity define a dependency on other configuration?

Tags: entities

In a custom module I am defining a defaults Configuration entity that references a role.
I would like to define a dependency on the role. This is my first attempt.

```
public function calculateDependencies() {
  $this->dependencies = parent::calculateDependencies();
  $this->addDependency('module', 'user');
  if (isset($this->role_id)) {
    $this->addDependency('config', "user.role.{$this->role_id}");
  }
  return $this; // Also tried return $this->dependencies;
}
```

The [Drupal documentation on dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-entity-dependencies) references the Block configuration class that looks very similar:

```
  public function calculateDependencies() {
    parent::calculateDependencies();
    $this->addDependency('theme', $this->theme);
    return $this;
  }
```

However I am seeing an error shown below when trying to save the entity.The backtrace indicates it is coming from the attempt to add a dependency on the user module. I chose to add that dependency by taking an example from `system.action.user_add_role_action.administrator`.

> PHP Error:  Cannot use object of type Drupal/my_module/Entity/MyAccessDefaults as array in /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/DependencyTrait.php on line 32

For example I am trying to test with this code:

```
$values = [
  'id' => 'administrator', 'label' => 'Administrator role grants', 
  'grant_type' => 'role', 'role_id' => "administrator", 
  'grants' => ['grant_view' => 1]
];
$default_admin_config = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('my_entity')->create($values);
$default_admin_config->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ConfigEntityInterface::calculateDependencies`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ConfigEntityInterface.php/function/ConfigEntityInterface%3A%3AcalculateDependencies/9.0.x) returns `$this`, so this line:

```
$this->dependencies = parent::calculateDependencies();
```

Is causing problems (replacing the dependencies array with the instance of the current class, which is presumably a `MyAccessDefaults`).

Looking at the code, and other core classes which implement `ConfigEntityInterface`, your code should be:

```
public function calculateDependencies() {
  parent::calculateDependencies();
  $this->addDependency('module', 'user');
  if (isset($this->role_id)) {
    $this->addDependency('config', "user.role.{$this->role_id}");
  }
  return $this;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I had just got it working when you answered with the same change. I think I copied that part from a sample somewhere.